# JPA hibernate ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities User and Venue. One user can have multiple venues. The table looks like this:
[image]

user_id is the foreign key in the Venue table.
I am trying to create a query for retrieving all Venues by user_id. This is what I have:

```
@Override
public List<Venue> findVenueByOwnerId(Long userId) {
        return em.createQuery("select v from Venue v where v.user.id = :ownerId", Venue.class)
                .setParameter("ownerId", userId)
                .getResultList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

These are my mappings:
For User class:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String email;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<Venue> venues;
```

For Venue class:

```
@Entity
public class Venue {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

private String name;
private String location;
private int capacity;

@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private User user;
```

And if I am trying to add getters and setters for the User in the Venue class, it throws me this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: razvan.sem3.project.model.User, at table: Venue, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]

Comment: `@JoinColumn` goes on the "many" side (`Venue` - you don't need it in the `User` class). You should not use `@Column`. Add `mappedBy="user"` in the `@OneToMany`. Also, this has nothing to do with Jersey. Please use only tags that are relevant to the question.

Comment: still having the same issues

Comment: I doubt it's the exact same error if you've made _all_ the changes I've suggested.